# unzip a specific file in the zip file uploaded by sp using java and google app engine

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I have trying to find out the solution for to unzip a particular file using java and Google app engine. I have tried using ZipInputStream but cant able to access the zip file that is uploaded in jsp. can any one help me to come out of this?

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
             resp.setContentType("text/plain");
             FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);
              while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                  FileItemStream fileItemStream = iterator.next();
                  InputStream InputStream = fileItemStream.openStream();
                  if (!fileItemStream.isFormField()) {
                      ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(InputStream));
                      ZipEntry entry;
                      while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

                          //code to access required file in the zip file
                      }

                  } 
              }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Peter. Please refer above, i have edited the code

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that `ZipInputStream` requires stream that is seekable. The streams returned by servlets (and networking in general) aren't seekable.

Try reading the whole stream, then wrapping it in `ByteArrayInputStream`:

```
byte[] bytes = readBytes(fileItemStream.openStream());
InputStream bufferedStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

public static byte[] readBytes(InputStream is) throws IOException {
  ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  int len;
  byte[] data = new byte[100000];
  while ((len = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    buffer.write(data, 0, len);
  }

  buffer.flush();
  return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: I am new to java. can you please tell me the process to read the zip file?